# TypeError: Cannot read property 'courses' of undefined, But network response is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data, undefined, apollo

Tengo este error me sale de vez en cuando, no siempre y dentro de las peticiones, la informacion si esta definida pero react asume que es undefined, no se si sea error de versiones o algo parecido

```
import React from 'react'
import CourseItem from '../microcomponents/CouseItem'
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import './styles/CoursesList.css'
import Loading from '../microcomponents/Loading';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const COURSES = gql`
query Courses{
    courses{
        id
        name
    }
}`;

function CoursesList (){
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(COURSES)
  if(loading){
    return <Loading/>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }
  return(
        <ul className="CoursesList">
          {data.courses.map((course) => {
        return (
          <CourseItem key={course.id} title={course.name} link={course.id}/>)
        })}
        </ul>
        )
    }

export default CoursesList
```

Estas son mis dependencias, antes no me presentaba este error, pero no se si es debido a una mala implementacion de mi parte o solo las dependencias incorrectas.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.21",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-relay": "^10.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentas que la respuesta está definida, y se supone que estás recibiendo algo en `data`, pero es probable que no sea la información esperada y solo necesitas una condición adicional para depurar:

```
function CoursesList (){
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(COURSES)
  if(loading){
    return <Loading/>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }
  // ¿data no tiene la propiedad courses?
  if(!data.hasOwnProperty('courses')) {
      // No hay cursos, hay que tratar de saber porqué
      return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  }
  return(
        <ul className="CoursesList">
          {data.courses.map((course) => {
        return (
          <CourseItem key={course.id} title={course.name} link={course.id}/>)
        })}
        </ul>
        )
}
```

Con esto podrías averiguar lo que está pasando y buscar la forma de solucionarlo. Ten en cuenta que solo es para depuración y debes evitarlo en producción, tal vez, cambiando un mensaje como *"Información no disponible por el momento"*.

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré el error, esta en la dependencia  "@apollo/client": "^3.3.21". Esta version genera un error en el cual se cumple esta condición que no deberia de cumplirse en ningún caso de la petición.

```
if(data === undefined && !loading && !error){
  console.log('tenemos un problema')
}
```

la ultima version compatible previa al error es la version 3.3.8